# Flask SQL-Alchemy Reflecting

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

Like in the [documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/models/) I try to reflect an existing table to work with.

My Code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy()
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "mssql+pyodbc://User:PW@localhost/DatabaseName?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
db.init_app(app)

with app.app_context():
    db.reflect()

class Test:
    __table__ = db.metadatas["DatabaseName"].tables["TableName"]
```

But I am getting a Key Error:

> KeyError: 'DatabaseName'

The User I use have full access to the DB.